# Handle ajax errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
$.getJSON("test.php", function(json) {
   ... this function handles success
});
```

How do I handle errors for the current `$.getJSON`?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?  The latest version (1.5) gives you new capabilities for handling errors.  See the release notes or `deferred.fail()` for more info on the new methods. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Comment: I'm using last stable - 1.4.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct option available using getJSON, instead use the ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
  },
  error: function(data){
   //ERROR HANDLING
  }
});
```

Comment: @Happy Take a look at the documentation. $.getJSON is only a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I've tryed this, it doesn't give any answer from the response

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the `jQuery.ajax` function.

It will let you create a GET request with an `error` and `success` callback.

An example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url:     "test.php",
   type:    "GET",
   success: function() { //... },
   error  : function() { //... }     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

```
$.ajaxError(function(){});
```

or you can switch to $.ajax and use the `error` property:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback,
  error: function(){
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it like this instead so you can specifically handle the error

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){}
  error: function(data){}
});
```

or you can use the global ajaxError